# Is there a Python function to randomly split a deepchem.data.NumpyDataset?

Tags: python, deep-learning, splitter

I am trying to split a deepchem.data.NumpyDataset into about 5 NumpyDatasets randomly in order to follow a Leave One Out approach to fitting a model. Every option for a function I have tried converts the dataset into an array or different kind of dataset or does not select data randomly.

I'm still a beginner to these modules so if someone is more familiar with deepchem I would greatly appreciate any help!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you just want training, validation and test splits, you could use one of the splitters in `deepchem.splits.splitters`. For example

```py
# assume dataset is a deepchem.data.NumpyDataset

from deepchem.splits.splitters import IndexSplitter

train_data, valid_data, test_data = splitter.split(dataset, frac_train=0.7, frac_valid=0.2, frac_test=0.1)
```

adapted from https://github.com/deepchem/deepchem/blob/master/examples/notebooks/Splitters_Tutorial.ipynb

Comment: Thank you for replying! I'm looking for a way that I can cycle through a for loop that would train a model using, for example, 4/5 of the training set to train and the final 1/5 to validate, then do this again but with a different selection of 4/5 and 1/5. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: It makes perfect sense, that's called cross validation by the way. I'm not super familiar with the `deepchem` library but one way you could achieve is by using the splitter multiple times.

`train_data_0, valid_data_0, _ = splitter.split(dataset, frac_train=0.8, frac_valid=0.2, frac_test=0.0)` then `train_data_1, valid_data_1, _ = splitter.split(dataset, frac_train=0.8, frac_valid=0.2, frac_test=0.0)` etc...

Comment: That's a great idea, I'll see what I can do with that! Thank you!